# SFML loadFromFile error

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, sfml

Im using CodeBlocks 16.01 and SFML GCC 4.9.2 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit on Windows 7
Only loadFromFile is not working and i have no idea what to do.
I tried to reinstall CodeBlocks, tried other versions of sfml but nothing worked.Im kinda new to SFML and its really frustrating.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int changeX = 0;
int changeY = 0;
int rot=0;

int main()
{
bool fscreen;
fscreen=false;
sf::Texture tex;
Sprite sprite;
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(640, 480,16), "SFML works!", Style::Default);
int direction=1,shiftX=10;

while(window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
        case Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            break;

        case Event::KeyPressed:
            if(event.key.code == Keyboard::Escape)
                window.close();
            if(event.key.code == Keyboard::F12)
            {
                fscreen = !fscreen;
                window.close();
                window.create(VideoMode(1920,1080,16), "SFML Test", (fscreen ? Style::Fullscreen : Style::Resize));
            }
            if (event.key.code==Keyboard::A)
                {
                changeX = -5;
                rot = -5;
                }
            else if (event.key.code==Keyboard::D)
                {
                changeX = 5;
                rot =5;
                }
                else
                {
                changeX = 0;
                }
            if (event.key.code==Keyboard::W)
                {
                changeY = -5;
                rot = 0;
                }
            else if (event.key.code==Keyboard::S)
                {
                changeY = 5;
                rot = 0;
                }
            else
                {
                changeY = 0;
                }
            break;
        }

    tex.loadFromFile("img\\obraz.png");

    sprite.move(changeX, changeY);
    sprite.setOrigin(100, 100);
    Vector2f origin = sprite.getOrigin();
    sprite.rotate(rot);
    sprite.setTexture(tex);
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Errors:

-undefined reference to `sf::Texture::loadFromFile(std::string const&,    sf::Rect const&)'

-error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The error you're showing us doesn't fit to the code you've posted. Are you sure that's the full code and exact error message?

Comment: It's a linker error,  did you link the program with `-lsfml-graphics`? Also don't load image in the game loop,  put it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The path you are giving to `loadFromFile` in

```
tex.loadFromFile("img\\obraz.png");
```

is a *relative* path. Meaning that it will be resolved relative to what your current working directory (look up `cwd()`) is.

You have two (easy) ways to solve your problem (there are others, but they are more difficult).

1) specify the full, absolute, path to the resource in the call to `loadFromFile` - like `tex.loadFromFile("C:/foo/bar/baz.png")`. This is obviously not attractive for several reasons, first and foremost that your program may be installed to a different location.

2) Stick to using a relative path but make sure you know what it is relative to by changing your programs working directory to some known location (probably relative to the location of the executable) at startup.

Comment: Absolute path didnt help, same as the other way to solve :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling the same code and it worked for me (except for the runtime error: "Failed to load image "img\obraz.png"" because obviously I don't have that image on my computer).

That means you must have installed SFML incorrectly. For your system specifications you should use this build of SFML: "GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (DW2) - 32-bit" (here is the download page: https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/). Also make sure to set it up correctly. I recommend you to watch video tutorial.